# Como crear una tabla en Postgres que admita números entre 0 y 100

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Debo crear una tabla con distintos atributos de una entidad, uno de ellos es crear una columna que admita números que se encuentren entre 0 y 100 ni mas, ni menos.
Soy bastante novato en este tema de las bases de datos y seria de

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. _Esta respuesta se reportó como de baja calidad debido a su extensión y contenido._

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar una `CONSTRAINTS` de tipo [`CHECK`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS), por ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE ejemplo (i int  CHECK ( i BETWEEN 0 AND 100));
```

También puedes usar un `DOMAIN`, si deses indagar más en ellos lee la [documemntación](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdomain.html)

Comment: Gracias, me ha funcionado perfecto